# powerdns responding to queries dig . NS @yournameserver

Tags: security, dns

I was told about security problem with responding to following queries:
dig . NS @yournameserver
I can't find if it affects my powerdns version 2.9.22-3 and how to prevent responding to that query.

My DNS server respond to above queries with:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> . NS @XX.XX.XX.XX
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49208
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 13, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 13
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.              IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
.           3600    IN  NS  A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.           3600    IN  NS  M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   128.63.2.53
B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   128.9.0.107
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   198.41.0.4
K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   193.0.14.129
G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   192.112.36.4
F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   192.5.5.241
D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   128.8.10.90
J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   198.41.0.10
I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   192.36.148.17
L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   198.32.64.12
C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   192.33.4.12
E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   192.203.230.10
M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET. 3600    IN  A   202.12.27.33

;; Query time: 62 msec
;; SERVER: XX.XX.XX.XX#53(XX.XX.XX.XX)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 23 12:58:44 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 449
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in your dig output is called a root referral, it basically means that the nameserver you are querying has builtin or configured knowledge of the IP addresses of the 13 root nameservers and is not afraid to let clients who query it know that, just like it would do with any other zone it is configured to answer for.

There is only one security problem that i can think of in a nameserver responding to IN NS queries on the basis of the data it is configured with is that a DNS query yields fewer bytes than the corresponding answer like we see in the above output and thus an authoritative or public recursive dns server could be used as a DoS amplifier.

You can prevent the output above by supplying data for the root zone on your authoritative nameserver.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> send-root-referral | --send-root-referral=yes | --send-root-referral=no | --send-root-referral=lean
> ```
>
> If set, PowerDNS will send out old-fashioned root-referrals when
>   queried for domains for which it is not authoritative. Wastes some
>   bandwidth but may solve incoming query floods if domains are delegated
>   to you for which you are not authoritative, but which are queried by
>   broken recursors. Available since 2.9.19.
>
> Since 2.9.21, it is possible to specify 'lean' root referrals, which
>   waste less bandwidth.

I suggest setting this option to =no or =lean.

Comment: I've added send-root-referral no/lean to pdns.conf then made test with this tool http://isc.sans.edu/dnstest.html. Still shows me "BAD, your name server responded to the query"